# How can I prevent concurrent logins in Identity Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am trying to find a solution for concurrent login issue in Identity server. For eg . if user logs in into 2 browsers at the same time then he should get logged out from the first one. In my case I am using this method UpdateSecurityStampAsync to update the security stamp, it is updating the security stamp, concurrency stamp and even SessionId in the db, but still it is not logging out the user from the first browser. Any suggestion is helpful, Thanks

Comment: There is no simple solution for that. What we did was store the session ids (in the cookie) after login and check them in separate custom made Middleware. If a user would change their password or something like that, all session ids would be invalidated, this request from invalid sessions would immediatly logout.

Comment: In Startup.cs look at the cookie lifetime in IDS4 middleware. Also in OWIN sign in, make sure persistence is set to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself resolved this by checking the session ids from the claims and comparing the same with the Identity server latest session by making calls to the IDS from client app on every click and on page reload. I won't suggest this solution, but this is the immediate fix that I have applied.